# How does the cloudflash-network module works

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'am trying to test [this](https://github.com/clearpath-networks/cloudflash-network) module with node.js but i can't understand how I can execute the queries given in the readme file, if someone could give a simple example would be great.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok it was simple. I just needed to run the zappa.js server given in the examples and connect via browser using the proper’s URI

example:

```
http://localhost:8080/network/interfaces
```